# R: Cut dataframe but ensure all steps

Tags: r

let's say I have this data:

```
test_data <- dplyr::tibble(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  values = c(40, 41, 38, 36, 35, 36, 30),
  times = c(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:00"),
            as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 15:00:00"),
            as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 18:00:00"),
            as.POSIXct("2020-01-02 14:00:00"),
            as.POSIXct("2020-01-03 20:00:00"),
            as.POSIXct("2020-01-05 10:00:00"),
            as.POSIXct("2020-01-05 14:00:00")))
```

I now want to extract the last value of each day, beginning with the first timestep. For that i do:

```
test_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(diff = as.double.difftime(times - min(times), units = "days")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(day = cut(diff, breaks = 0:6, include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE, ordered_result = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(ID, day) %>%
  filter(row_number()==n()) %>%
  select(ID, day, values) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = day, values_from = values)
```

which gives:

```
     ID `[0,1]` `(1,2]` `(2,3]` `(4,5]`
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1      38      36      35      30
```

However, as you see there is a step missing as we have no data from day 3 to 4. Is there a way to ensure that alle intervals are included in the result and that for missing data NA is placed instead?
My only idea would be to add a "dummy user" to the dataframe that has data for all intervals so that it is ensured that all intervals are included.
So what i want is:

```
     ID `[0,1]` `(1,2]` `(2,3]` `(3,4]` `(4,5]`
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      38      36      35   NA   30
```

Comment: complete(day) did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can fill missing rows in your dataset looking for missing dates like that:

```
seq_dates <- tibble(times = seq(min(unique(as.Date(test_data$times))), max(unique(as.Date(test_data$times))), by="days"))
missing_dates <- seq_dates %>% filter(!times %in% unique(as.Date(test_data$times)))
missing_dates$times <- as.POSIXct(missing_dates$times)
missing_dates$ID <- 1
missing_dates$values <- NA
missing_dates <- missing_dates %>% select(ID, values, times)
test_data <- test_data %>% bind_rows(missing_dates) %>% arrange(times)
```

And then execute your code:

```
test_data %>%
dplyr::mutate(diff = as.double.difftime(times - min(times), units = "days")) %>%
dplyr::mutate(day = cut(diff, breaks = 0:6, include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE, ordered_result = TRUE)) %>%
group_by(ID, day) %>%
filter(row_number()==n()) %>%
select(ID, day, values) %>%
tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = day, values_from = values)
```

And get the desired result:

```
    ID `[0,1]` `(1,2]` `(2,3]` `(3,4]` `(4,5]`
 <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1      38      36      35      NA      30
```